# How do I query HTML embedded inside a string inside a JSON file with Apache Drill?

Tags: html, json, apache-drill

I'm trying to use Apache Drill (for the first time) on a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
    "Key1": {
      "htmltags": "<htmltag attr1='bravo' /><htmltag attr2='delta' /><htmltag attr3='charlie' />"
    },
    "Key2": {
      "htmltags": "<htmltag attr1='kilo' /><htmltag attr2='lima' /><htmltag attr3='mike' />"
    },
    "Key3": {
      "htmltags": "<htmltag attr1='november' /><htmltag attr2='foxtrot' /><htmltag attr3='sierra' />"
    }
}
```

My initial query was the hello world of drill: `SELECT * FROM DataFile.json`, and returned me the columns `Key1`, `Key2`, `Key3`. They only had one row, and it contained the entry:
`"<htmltag attr1='bravo' /><htmltag attr2='delta' /><htmltag attr3='charlie' />"` [*i.e.,* only the entry `Key1.htmltags`].

I have two questions:

1. **Why was there only one row returned, when there were three differently valued entries for each key?**
2. **After using the KVGEN/FLATTEN functions to get at my strings inside "htmltags" above, is there a way to drill further into (analyse and extract data from) the HTML tags?**

Comment: Can't validate the json you posted or get a result from Drill running your hello world query. Please check the json you used against the post.

Comment: @catpaws this was representative of the original, sorry I didn't check for validity. I'll correct it.

Comment: @catpaws edited, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like Drill isn't the right tool (v1.1.0 as of this writing on Homebrew) for the job.

1. It looks like there is a bug with the system which is the reason why there is only one row despite multiple columns. I've filed a report: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-4102
2. I've scoured the documentation once again, there are no tools to analyse HTML or XML natively. Depending on string manipulation for this is [not a task I relish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/443219).

Hence, I'll go with an XML parser, DOM tree crawler or the like, and use a bash string function to extract the target tag strings awk/tee.

Comment: There's some experimental support for XML as a data source here: https://github.com/magpierre/drill/tree/DRILL-3878/contrib/storage-xml Maybe this could help?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON seems to be not well formed.
The objects are not clearly identified by a name/value pair. Nor is it a clear array.

Once that is resolved, the values for htmltags will have to be handled with string functions such as locate,substr,position, etc (See https://drill.apache.org/docs/string-manipulation/)

Best may be to have the htmltags as arrays vs just a string.

Comment: I agree that the structure doesn't seem optimal, but this is what I was supplied to work with :( could you expand a little bit on the string handling function part with an example?